# Querying @ManyToMany with unmapped @JoinTable with hibernate in a spring-mvc app

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have two entities. `(Find code below)`

I am trying to write a query that would count `customDetails=:myCriteria` of `EntitiesA` that are associated to `EntityB` of specific `id`.

I have written the necessary query using `session.CreateSQLQuery` that reads the `associated_entitites` table, however, I am unable to use it as the `customDetails` column is encrypted by hibernate's `@ColumnTransformer` and returns a `BLOB`. And I cannot replicate it in HQL as `associated_entities` is not mapped.

> a

```
@Entity
public class entityA{


@Id
private int id;

@Column
@ColumnTransformer
private CustomDetails customDetails;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "entitiesA")
private List<entityB> entitiesB;

//getters and setters
}
```

> b

```
@Entity
public class entityB{


@Id
private int id;

@JoinTable(name = "associated_entities",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "entityB_id") })
private List<EntityA> entitiesA;

//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution I have found and is much preferred as the logic is performed by hibernate, which I have found to be a lot more faster, is to use **two separate queries** and utilise `where :foo in elements()`

Code example below (not matching question example, but idea and use of `elements()` should be clear)

```
Query<Object1> q1 = currentSession.createQuery("from Object1 o where o.objectNumber= :objectNumber");
        q1.setParameter("objectNumber", objectNumber);
        Object1 obj1 = q1.getSingleResult();
        Query<Long> q2 = currentSession.createQuery("select count(id) from Object2 o where :object1param in elements(o.associatedObjects));
        q2.setParameter("object1param ", obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found, but is not ideal as the logic is not done by hibernate. Had to write the logic in the `DAOImpl`.

Example code:

```
public Long getQuery(String criteria, String, fromdate, String todate){
    Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery(
                    "from EntityA a "+
                    "where a.CustomDetails >= :from "+
                    "and a.CustomDetails <= :to");
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            LocalDate From = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, formatter);
            LocalDate To = LocalDate.parse(toDate, formatter);
            theQuery.setParameter("from", From);
            theQuery.setParameter("to", To);
            Long count = (long)0;
            List<EntityA> entities= theQuery.list();
            for(EntityA EA:entities) {
                for(EntityB EB: EA.getEntityB()) {
                    if(EB.someValue().equals(criteria)) count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
```